# Can't add a new ID to Volume Purchase Program Customers

Tags: ios-appstore, apple-id, app-store-connect, volume-purchase-program

I have an app that I sell using Apple B2B / VPP. When logging into iTunes connect to add a new Apple ID (for a new customer) I am finding that clicking "Add Apple Id" is doing nothing (e.g. the page reloads, but I can't add a new Id).

Presumably this is just a short term issue with the iTunes connect website? (I've been having the problem since yesterday).

I've tried using Firefox, Safari, and Chrome; and connected on a few different networks to rule out my router.

**Is anyone else seeing the same issue?**

Comment: Try a different browser, if the problem persists contact apple

Answer (score 1):

Apple website is broken and has been since 3/13.  I opened case#769729461 for this.  They are working on it, no ETA on a fix.

Comment: Thanks Kimberlee. Apple just got back to me with a similar response; they mentioned that it is a global issue, so hopefully they'll fix it soon.